# How do i get certain information about a channel using Youtube APIs "statistics"

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get certain values from different channels using

```
request = youtube.channels().list(part = "statistics",id = ChannelID)
responseYT = request.execute()
print(responseYT)
```

The statistics part is showing a lot of information like views, subscriber count etc. but its doing it in an unreadable way.
How could I take, for example just the subscriber count and display that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `responseYT` is a Python dict, you can walk through it and as you requested a single channel, you just pick the first item. So it gives:

```
print(responseYT['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])
```